# SQL: Expand existing table by permutating the starting item

Tags: sql, combinations, permutation, vertica

I have a `N x M` table in a vertica database, my goal is to create a new table with `N*M x M` such that each row in the initial table is replaced by M rows where the starting item is permuated.

Here is an example for a `2 x 3` Table

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | C     |
| C     | K     | L     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Becoming a `6 x 3` Table where every row from the original row got replaced by 3 new rows where Item1 is always a different starting item.

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| A     | B     | C     |
| B     | A     | C     |
| C     | A     | B     |
| C     | K     | L     |
| K     | C     | L     |
| L     | C     | K     |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is there an elegant solution to that sort of problem, I tried using joining in various ways, but so far no luck. Thanks!!

Comment: There is not an elegant soution.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help you in the general case. In the specific case would this work in Vertica?

```
select
    case n 
        when 1 then item1
        when 2 then item2
        else item3
    end as item1,
    case n 
        when 1 then item2
        when 2 then item3
        else item1
    end as item2,
    case n 
        when 1 then item3
        when 2 then item1
        else item2
    end as item3
from tab
cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n) as b
```

I'm a SQL Server man myself, and it would be straight forward to make this query dynamically from the definition of the table (given reasonable constraints on the table metadata), but alas, I do not know Vertica

Comment: This works in Vertica, I am generating my querries with python, so I will try and come up with a routine that works for the general case. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking why not just use a bunch of unions like that

```
SELECT Item1, Item2, Item3 from Table
union SELECT Item2, Item3, Item1 from Table
UNION SELECT Item3, Item1, Item2 from Table
```

That should give the same result, no?